# Hadoop: High CPU load on client side after committing jobs

Tags: client, hadoop, jobs, cpu-usage

I couldn't find an answer to my issue while sifting through some Hadoop guides: I am committing various Hadoop jobs (up to 200) in one go via a shell script on a client computer. Each job is started by means of a JAR (which is quite large; approx. 150 MB). Right after submitting the jobs, the client machine has a very high CPU load (each core on 100%) and the RAM is getting full quite fast. That way, the client is no longer usable. I thought that the computation of each job is entirely done within the Hadoop framework, and only some status information is exchanged between the cluster and the client while the job is running.

So, why is the client fully stretched? Am I committing Hadoop jobs the wrong way? Is each JAR too big?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about the jar. The client side is calculating the `InputSplits`.
So it can be possible that when having large number of input files for each job the client machine gets a lot of load.
But I guess when submitting 200 jobs the RPC Handler on the jobtracker has some problems. How many RPC handlers are active on the jobtracker?

Anyways, I would batch the submission up to 10 or 20 jobs at a time and wait for their completion. I guess you're having the default FIFO scheduler? So you won't benefit from submitting all 200 jobs at a time either.

Comment: I wasn't aware of a configuration of RPC handlers for the jobtracker. The value in mapred-site.xml is set to 40. I'm using the FairScheduler.

Comment: Well, you could increase it a bit. But the memory usage from calculating the input splits will still be there.

Comment: Also, the jar file has to be copied to HDFS. 200 jobs * 150 MB ~ 30 GB to HDFS from the client. Also, mapred.submit.replication is defaulted to 10 (so 30 GB has to be replicated 10 times in HDFS). Documentation says this replication should be square root of the number of nodes. Not sure if decreasing this replication makes things faster.

Comment: @PraveenSripati Thanks for your insights. Indeed, the mapred.submit.replication value is still set to the default value. I have about 40 nodes in my cluster, so I'll try to decrease the value to 6. In addition, I'll try to minimize the size of my JAR, because the replication and network traffic caused is very high.

Comment: @Thomas - `I guess you're having the default FIFO scheduler? So you won't benefit from submitting all 200 jobs at a time either.` - Just curious how does it matter?

Comment: Leaving priority aside, the first job will finish first, while all other jobs are queued up. This takes large amounts of memory on JobTracker and Tasktracker though.

Comment: If the jar file is large and is repeated across jobs, you could put the file in HDFS using the put command and setrep command (for the replication). And then use '-libjars' Generic Options to specify the location of the jar file in HDFS when running the job. The jar file will be copied locally to the TaskTracker node and put in the task's classpath. This way the common jar file is not copied again and again for each job (200 in your case). Since the jar file has been copied manually to HDFS, it has to be deleted manually when all the jobs are complete.

Comment: I raised a [query](http://goo.gl/gEYWl) in MapRedDev forum on why the InputSplit calculation should happen on the client m/c. There is already a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-207) open on this already to move it from the user code. If the JIRA gets resolved, then the client m/c can be dumb :)

Comment: @Thomas - The TaskTracker need not be aware of the Jobs in the Queue.